# How to Load an alternate bean when some certain conditions don't apply

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using a service that relies on a third party jar which contains classes class called SSLModuleConnector and BasicConnectorModule.  The class Saml2Moulde uses SSL and Saml in addition to keys, private and public certificates that are signed by an authority like Verisign and it is used for instantiating the SSLModuleConnector so it will possess all the code to load keys, created secure connections etc.

However, the setup to use the module class Saml2Module is not available in some lower environments, for example, the dev environment. To work around this limitation  I have to be able to configure a bean without the Saml2Module in that environment, otherwise, the tests would fail because the application context cannot be loaded.  There is an alternative class called BasicModuleConnector which uses non-SSL written to be used in place of the Saml2Module when working in the lower environments which do not have the signed keys available for use.  I am not sure how to get the replacement to be autowired in the event where the Saml2Module cannot be used. In a nutshell, I want to inject BasicConnectorModule when Saml2Module will throw an exception because the keys are not present. If the keys are present I want to return a SSLModuleConnector.

The configuration with the  ConditionalOnProperty uses a flag, that I place in the application-dev-properties file with its value set to false. 
However, I also want to be able to load the BasicConnectorModule as a replacement when the Saml2Module class throws an exception and I therefore cannot create SSLModuleConnector. Both beans implement an interface ModuleConnector. In the class which uses the bean, I want to autowire ModuleConnector. The Saml2Module class has the @Service annotation in it. (I agree the providers named it very inappropriately, but I cannot change it.). It is in a jar I pull in my classpath.

```
@Service
class OrderWebService {

    ModuleConnector moduleConnector;
    ....
```

}

If I were to state this in pseudocode,

```
When the property use.saml.policy is set to true, create autowire the bean SSLModuleConnector, else load the BasicConnectorModule bean.
```

Here is my attempt to get one of the beans;

```
//This works when in the prod and uat environments
@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "use.saml.policy", havingValue = "true")
ModuleConnector secureSSLModule(@Value("${key.store.path}") String keyStorePath , 
                            Saml2Module moduleService) {
   SSLModuleConnector connector = new SSLModuleConnector(moduleService)  ;
   connector.keyStorePath(keyStorePath)
   return connector;
```

}

```
//This is the bean to load when the Saml2Module is not to be used.
//I want to load this when the Saml2Module will cause the bean to fail to load
// How do I get these 2 beans to coexist in the same configure and get a ModuleConnector?

@Bean
ModuleConnector secureSSLModule() {
    BasicModuleConnector connector = new BasicModuleConnector(null)  ;
    connector.useSecurity(false);
   return connector;
```

}

I am using @SpringBootApplication in the main class, which has @EnableAutoConfiguration.

Comment: Look up the annotation `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`

Comment: That would not work because the library is in the classpath. it is a 3rd party library. The issue is that all the required keystore pieces and services it needs are not set up in some environments so I need to create the alternate been in those situations like I showed in the second bean. I just don't know how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "use.saml.policy", havingValue = "true")
ModuleConnector secureSSLModule(@Value("${key.store.path}") String keyStorePath,
                                Saml2Module moduleService) {
    try {
        SSLModuleConnector connector = new SSLModuleConnector(moduleService);
        connector.keyStorePath(keyStorePath)
        return connector;
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        return secureSSLModule(e);
    }
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "use.saml.policy", havingValue = "false", matchIfMissing = true)
ModuleConnector secureSSLModule() {
    BasicModuleConnector connector = new BasicModuleConnector(null);
    connector.useSecurity(false);
    return connector;
}
```

Comment: I will attempt to improve my description of the problem. Thank you

Comment: How do I use the property use.saml.policy? I need to be able to know in which environment it is suitable to autowire the class Saml2Module.

Comment: Ah now I see. There's the possibility that the @Bean creation itself throws an exception and in that case you want to create the other @Bean? Is that right? In what cases would it throw an exception?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I'm sorry I wasn't very explicit, to begin with.  Many thanks for your help. It throws an IllegalStateException.

Comment: The thing is, if you are not writing an AutoConfiguration (which I assume you aren't), you will have problems with the ordering of your Conditions, but in any case, I'll update my answer in a bit with an "example" of which directino you should go to.

Comment: see my updated answer. it has the advantage that it doesn't need specific re-ordering, which is a bit trickier to do with the @Conditionals

Comment: Thanks a lot Marco, i will try this solution, very much appreciated!

Comment: One thing I observe is that when I try to autowire the ModuleConnector in my web service class i.e. OrderWebService, Spring complains that there is more than one type with ModuleConnector bean. Can I give both beans the same name or is there a better way to specify the autowired bean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211093/discussion-between-breendeen-and-marco-behler).

Comment: Thank you, very much.